# Pm2 logs with huge size using pm2-logrotate

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2, pm2-logrotate

I'm having troubles with pm2.

I'm using a module called pm2-logrotate but the logs have a huge gize like 1.7G and don't respect my configuration which is

```
== pm2-logrotate ==
┌────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ key            │ value         │
├────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ compress       │ true          │
│ rotateInterval │ * * */1 * * * │
│ max_size       │ 10M           │
│ retain         │ 1             │
│ rotateModule   │ true          │
│ workerInterval │ 30            │
└────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

So what can I do to pm2 can delete the old logs and dont start crushing my machine with a huge amount of data?

Comment: I had this same problem, the solution for me was run `pm2 flush` first, and then install and configure the `pm2-logrotate`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. I think there's currently a bug in `pm2-logrotate` where the `workerInterval` option is ignored, and it only rotates according to the `rotateInterval` option (i.e. once per day by default). And that means that the files can get much bigger than the size you specified with the `max_size` option. See options [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-logrotate#configure).

I "solved" it by setting the `rotateInterval` option to every 30 mins instead of the default of once per day. Here's the command:

```
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:rotateInterval '*/30 * * * *'
```

The problem with this is that it means your logs will rotate every 30 mins no matter what size they are. Another temporary solution would be to run `pm2 flush` (which deletes all logs) with crontab. First run `crontab -e` in your terminal, and then add this line to the file:

```
*/30 * * * * pm2 flush
```

You can also flush a specific app with `pm2 flush your_app_name` if you've got a particular app that produces a lot of logs. If you're not good at remembering how cron timing syntax works (like me), you can use [this site](https://crontab.guru/every-30-minutes).